C# Command Prompt Connection Broken
I'm creating a server launcher in WPF using the .NET Framework to avoid manual file adjustments each time. Currently, I can interact with the server's batch file from my GUI, but I'm running into issues when I switch views. For example, when I navigate away from the console screen (to settings, logs, etc.), I lose connection to the running command prompt, and inputs and outputs stop working, even though the server process is still active.
Here's the key for my setup:
tb: TextBox for command input
lb: Label to show server status
CurrentServer: Represents the selected server instance in various controls
I've tried several solutions (see below), but nothing has worked so far. Is there a better approach to maintain interaction with the running server command prompt after switching views?
Similar Issue Reference - but I need to maintain real-time input/output.
(How to pass commands to already running command prompt in C#?)
private Process cmdProcess;
private bool isServerOnline = false;

public void ComandPromptRun()
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

    // Check if the process for the current server already exists
    if (mainWindow.MinecraftJavaCmdProcesses.ContainsKey(mainWindow.CurrentServer) && mainWindow.MinecraftJavaCmdProcesses[mainWindow.CurrentServer] != null)
    {
        cmdProcess = mainWindow.MinecraftJavaCmdProcesses[mainWindow.CurrentServer];

        if (cmdProcess != null && !cmdProcess.HasExited)
        {
            // Reattach output event handler
            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived -= CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived; 
            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;

            // Ensure the process is still reading output
            if (cmdProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CanRead)
            {
                cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine(); // Reattach reading
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The output stream is unavailable. Please restart the process.");
            }

            // Load previous logs if any
            foreach (var log in mainWindow.MinecraftJavaLogs[mainWindow.CurrentServer])
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    TB_ComandPromptOutput.AppendText(log + Environment.NewLine);
                });
            }

            return; // Avoid starting a new process
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Process has exited or is unavailable. You will need to restart the server.");
            mainWindow.MinecraftJavaCmdProcesses[mainWindow.CurrentServer] = null;
        }
    }

    // Start a new process if it doesn't exist
    StartNewMinecraftProcess(mainWindow);
}

private void StartNewMinecraftProcess(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    string selectedServerPath = mainWindow.MinecraftJavaServers[mainWindow.CurrentServer];

    // Start a new thread to run the server process
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Starting server at: {selectedServerPath}");
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

            cmdProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = $@"{selectedServerPath}\Run.bat",
                    WorkingDirectory = selectedServerPath,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived;
            cmdProcess.Start();
            cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            // Store the new process in the dictionary
            mainWindow.MinecraftJavaCmdProcesses[mainWindow.CurrentServer] = cmdProcess;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show($"Failed to start server: {ex.Message}"));
        }

    }).Start();
}

private void CmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // Append to TextBox
            TB_ComandPromptOutput.AppendText(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);

            // Store log in the MainWindow dictionary
            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            if (!mainWindow.MinecraftJavaLogs.ContainsKey(mainWindow.CurrentServer))
            {
                mainWindow.MinecraftJavaLogs[mainWindow.CurrentServer] = new List<string>();
            }
            mainWindow.MinecraftJavaLogs[mainWindow.CurrentServer].Add(e.Data);
        });
    }
}

public void CmdProcess_IncomeDataSent(string inputData)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputData))
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (cmdProcess != null && !cmdProcess.HasExited)
            {
                if (cmdProcess.StandardInput != null && !cmdProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The input stream is closed or unavailable.");
                    return;
                }

                cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(inputData);
                cmdProcess.StandardInput.Flush();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Command prompt process is not running or has exited.");
            }
        });
    }
}

private void TB_ComandPromptInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        CmdProcess_IncomeDataSent(TB_ComandPromptInput.Text);
        if (TB_ComandPromptInput.Text.ToLower() == "stop")
        {
            lb_IsServerOnline.Content = "Offline";
            lb_IsServerOnline.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            TB_ComandPromptInput.IsEnabled = false;
            isServerOnline = false;
        }
        TB_ComandPromptInput.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}

What I've Tried:
Switching to PowerShell with similar code.
Running the process on different threads.
Running the process without the batch file using arguments directly in code.
Storing command processors in the main window.
Running everything through Dispatcher.Invoke.
ChatGPT and other AI-based tools for assistance.
